# Reset NodeMCU master from Arduino slave

Tags: nodemcu

I designed a PWS (personal weather station) which will be placed in a difficult to access location.  In case of the master crashing and not requesting from the slave for a certain amount of time (stay alive protocol), is it possible to reset the master from the slave by powering a digital pin?

[image]

Note, I improvised a pull down circuit so that the Arduino Nano's D7 (or any other digital pin) 5V output could be pulled down to 3.3V.

Comment: for me it didn't work for Wemos D1 mini. with level shifter it worked. I don't know why. but you should have a level shifter for esp8266 RX too

Comment: care to elaborate into an answer?  tks @Juraj

Comment: I plan esp-01S wiring experiments this weekend and the reset of the esp8266 from Arduino is one of the goals

Comment: The "RST" (reset pin) should work, try it w/o the other device, to see if it actually resets.

Comment: @Juraj da man!  tell me how that goes, please!  Do you want me to post this fritzing diagram as an fzz somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a voltage divider or a level conversion on the reset pin of the esp8266. The esp8266 has internal pull-up on reset pin. To reset the esp8266 the reset pin must be connected to ground for a very short moment.

To pull the reset pin LOW with pin of the other MCU we do:

```
void resetEsp() {
  pinMode(ESP_RESET_PIN, OUTPUT);
  delay(1);
  pinMode(ESP_RESET_PIN, INPUT);
}
```

ESP_RESET_PIN is the pin wired to reset pin of the esp8266. It is not configured in `setup()` and it is never set `HIGH` (we don't want to send 5 V to esp8266). Setting the ESP_RESET_PIN to `OUTPUT` connects it to ground, setting it back to `INPUT` hands the control of the line back to esp8266 reset pin's internal pull-up.

Comment: not sure i understand the wiring.  Does that mean that my Arduino (MCU) digital out is connected directly to NodeMCU RST pin?  If not, do you  mind posting a Fritzing diagram?  `UPVOTED` pending clarification for eventual `ACCEPT AS CORRECT ANSWER`.

Comment: i am posting a Fritzing as an answer, please comment if correct or incorrect.  Vote (up or down) if you will.

Comment: yes direct connection, because there is never 5 V from Nano side. it only pulls the reset LOW

Comment: ACCEPTED, tks!!

Answer (score 0):

As per verification from Juraj, this would be correct wiring for his answer:

[image]

Comment: the point of reset from other MCU is not in wiring, but in code.

Comment: so is my original diagram correct, with the voltage divider?

Comment: I removed my comments about level conversion on I2C following Majenko's explanation here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/67461/arduino-slave-with-2-masters-sharing-the-same-i2c-bus/67462?noredirect=1#comment145475_67462

Comment: as I write in the answer you don't need voltage divider on reset because it has nothing to divide. there is never 5 V

Comment: so, this wiring would work?

Comment: yes. of course there is a risk that some other unintentionally to Nano uploaded sketch sets the pin as output high.